# C program: segmentation fault when trying to populate dynamically created array

Tags: c

I am working on a homework assignment that requires the creation of a dynamically allocated array which is to be populated with strings from a text file. I then need to print the array to standard output, shuffle the array, and then print it again.

My current issue is that I cannot seem to populate the array with anything without getting a segmentation fault. I tested the program with a static array and everything worked, so I know there isn't an issue with any of the other code.

Here is a section of my program.

```
void alloc2dArray(char ***source, int dim1, int dim2)
{
    int i = 0;

    source = malloc(sizeof(char *) * dim1);

    if(source == NULL) 
    { 
        printf("Memory full!");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
    for(i = 0; i < dim1; i++)
    {
            source[i] = malloc(sizeof(char) * (dim2 + 1));
            if(source[i] == NULL) 
        { 
            printf("Memory full!"); 
            exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
        }
    }
}
```

---

**EDIT:**

In an effort to avoid being a Three Star Programmer I changed my code to the below snippet. As luck would have it, that fixed my issue. So thanks to Kniggug for posting the link to something I had no idea about before.

```
char** alloc2dArray(int dim1, int dim2)
{
        int i = 0;

        char **twoDArray = malloc(sizeof(char *) * dim1);

        if(twoDArray == NULL)
        {
                printf("Memory full!");
                exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
        }
        for(i = 0; i < dim1; i++)
        {
                (twoDArray[i]) = malloc(sizeof(char) * (dim2 + 1));
                if(twoDArray[i] == NULL)
                {
                        printf("Memory full!");
                        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
                }
        }

        return twoDArray;
}
```

Thank you.

Comment: [Three star programmer!](http://c2.com/cgi/wiki?ThreeStarProgrammer)

Comment: The answers posted look right, but you should understand why they're correct. The above code in the `alloc2dArray` function is modifying a copy of the address of `**source`. What you need to do is modify the value pointed to by `***source`, which is accomplished through `*source` as mentioned twice below.

Comment: jucestain, thanks for the clarification. I am still trying to wrap my head around pointers. This is only an intro course and my first time trying my hand at C.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
Void alloc2dArray(char ***source, int dim1, int dim2)
{
    int i = 0;

    source = malloc(sizeof(char *) * dim1);
```

The assignment above has no effect outside this function, apart from leaking memory. You mean to do:

```
    *source = malloc(sizeof(char *) * dim1);
```

similarly:

```
(*source)[i] = malloc(sizeof(char) * (dim2 + 1));
```

Comment: I appreciate the quick response. I tried the changes that you suggested, but that caused a segmentation fault even if I comment out the problem strcpy line. I have included more of the program to perhaps help figure out if I have a larger issue.

Comment: Do you have valgrind installed? If so run under valgrind, if not use a debugger to see where it crashes.

Comment: @Chad, also set the maxChars to something larger than 0

Comment: Thanks again for the help perreal. I tried Valgrind and found that I had several errors as well as leaks. This prompted me to try to rework the code and I was able to fix it.

Answer (score 1):

Change `source` to `(*source)` in `alloc2dArray`

```
Void alloc2dArray(char ***source, int dim1, int dim2)
{
    int i = 0;

    *source = malloc(sizeof(char *) * dim1);

    if(*source == NULL)
    {
        printf("Memory full!");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
    for(i = 0; i < dim1; i++)
    {
        (*source)[i] = malloc(sizeof(char) * (dim2 + 1));
        if((*source)[i] == NULL)
        {
                printf("Memory full!");
                exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
        }
    }
}
```